I need to copy one private image to my private repo, how can I do that?
I have to use one private image, which I found under AMIs of ec2 of AWS. I want to use this image in my existing docker file, where , I had given the path of another image, from my private repo. Please suggest me the way to use that private image in my docker file, or the way using which I can copy that private image to my private repo.
I have already my private repo created. I have ready to use docker file for another image, which is available in my private repo.
